# luks encryption passphrase fails if dock is connected

Tags: luks, thinkpad, dock

If my ThinkPad P1 gen4 is connected to Lenovo Thunderbolt4-dock (0B40 series).

I'm not able to start. My root- and home-partitions are encrypted with luks. At boot I'm asked for passphrase, for decrypting root-partition. This works if it is not attached to dock.
If it is connected, after I wrote passphrase, but I get

```
no key available with this passphrase
```

Why the dock is blocking decrypting partition?